# Laravel get requests from multipart/form-data in POST method

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, multipartform-data

I'm receiving third party request to my laravel post API with two form-data (ID, File) with headers (**Content-type multipart/form-data**)

In laravel controller, not getting requests in `$request->all()`, But could see the form-data in `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

In the same request without content-type multipart-formdata, it's working fine, getting requests - id & file. (I've checked in Postman with same third party request params)

Content type as multipart-formdata is requesting from third-party, So couldn't remove or modify the headers. how to properly receive it in laravel using POST method?

Please guide.

Comment: What does `$request->getContent()` give you?

Comment: Same like file_get_contents('php://input') But whether that result can be parse to get the input id and file(pdf)

Comment: Are you applying any third party middleware to your apis routes?

Comment: No, not applying any middlewares

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is correct and file name is `myfile`,
You should get it as

```
$file  = $request->file('myfile');
```

in your controller or other class like FormRequest class or Validation class

Comment: Thanks. $request->file & $reqeust->all both returns empty array only.

Comment: @Tamilvanan, can you go to source code and post the HTML in your question?